# wget error using Codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, wget

I'm attempting to download a file from a website using `wget`. I can type directly in the command prompt and `wget` will run just fine, but once I attempt to run the same code from CodeBlocks, I get an error:

"'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Any ideas? I've attached the code I'm using in code blocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    system("wget http://registry.faa.gov/database/AR082015.zip -P D:/Downloads");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `D:/Downloads` looks like Windows. Is `wget` installed on Windows?

Comment: It is installed. I can run wget from cmd.

Comment: 1) be sure the wget utility is in the $PATH.  2) include the actual path in the 'system()' parameter  3) be sure the wget utility is marked as executable (and the directory(s) above it)  4) use the correct '\' or '/' is the various parts of the command line

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: `D:/`. In Windows, that's: `D:\`*(two escape backward slashes)*.

Answer (score 0):

It might work for you:

```
int main()
{
    system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin\\wget.exe\" http://registry.faa.gov/database/AR082015.zip -P D:/Downloads");
    return 0;
}
```

Where *\"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe\"*  replace with your installation bin path.

EDIT: For first time installation of wget, restart may solve your problem.